# MYSQL How to use trim in select query

Tags: sql, mysql, string

my table have set of records around 50,

in the table i have column called `USERNAME`, but some of username leading and trailing have the white space ,

so am not getting exact order result because of white space,

So tell me how to use the trim in `SELECT` query ,

Thanks

Comment: you may want to update the table to remove the whitespace, and trim new records on insert rather than spend processing cycles on trimming every time you query.  update myTable set USERNAME = trim(USERNAME)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use [TRIM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) in the ORDER BY:

```
ORDER BY TRIM(username)
```

...but this will only trim excess space on the left and right side of the text, not in between.

Using TRIM in the SELECT is as easy as:

```
SELECT TRIM(username) AS username
  FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) in your query to remove all whitespaces from strings, e.g.:

```
SELECT REPLACE(A.Postal, ' ', '') AS Postal FROM ADDRESS
```

Be aware that this will remove all whitespaces, not only the leading and tailing ones.

Comment: That also replaces spaces inside the content, not just leading and trailing spaces.