# How to replace the first character of a column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table and in that I want to sort a column in that table. But I’m unable to get the sorted order because there are different kinds of characters in the first place of the string. Some of them have horizontal tab, some of them have spaces, and some of them are empty. I have tried trim method but it doesn’t work for me. I have nearly 200000 records in that table. I cant update the table. I need a select query which should give the result neglecting all the unnecessary things and should sort the columns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL How to use trim in select query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632760/mysql-how-to-use-trim-in-select-query)

Comment: Substring function requires 3 arguments

Comment: Trim function will remove only spaces Some records have horizonal tab

Comment: It is possible to use substring with specify length as specified [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring). Anyway, substring probably won't work as not all string start from the same positions

Comment: please post sample data and expected result

Comment: You tagged both mysql and sql-server. Which of those two databases are you using?

Comment: I have to write query in both databases

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
ORDER BY IF(coloum_name LIKE "_%", substr(coloum_name, 1), coloum_name);
```

Explanation:
We use the `IF` function to strip the first character from the beginning of the string before returning the string to the `ORDER BY` clause. For more complex rules we could create a user-defined function and place that in the `ORDER BY` clause instead. Then you would have ...`ORDER BY MyFunction(coloum_name)`

For SQL Server, do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
ORDER BY CASE WHEN coloum_name LIKE "_%" THEN substr(coloum_name, 1) ELSE coloum_name END
```

Comment: This has worked for me, I don't know about your data, Please post a sample data and the required result.

Comment: SELECT *
FROM SYSTEM_CORRESPOND
ORDER BY IF(SUBJECT LIKE "_%", substr(SUBJECT, 1), SUBJECT);

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near ','.